# PHP Commands - Does echo count for @return

Tags: php, comments

I comment my whole PHP-Code with
@param
@return
and so on, but how do I comment if the PHP-function echo's some HTML code?
Is there an extra @ comment or how do I write it?

```
/**
 * @param void
 * @return void???
 */
public function example(){
   echo "<h1>Hello</h1>";
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Why should you want to do that? Use views or template engines like smarty that are responsible for outputting HTML. You shouldn't have methods that output HTML.

Comment: If you do not have a return value, you can use `void`. If you do not have paramters, leave the `@params` out.

Comment: Don't drastically change your question.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request). In this way it will no longer stick to your profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer **No**.
It's recommended to use any template framework engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), in that you just need to pass PHP variables into a corrsponding file and render the view as you want.

They have very reach library and support.

Comment: I just reformulate my question, can you have a look at it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should adress this question :

```
$result = myAwesomeFunction();
print_r($result);
```

If the output is empty, your function does not return anything (so void).

In fact, printing is completly different from instanciating a variable. But you may print some information AND returning a value.